# How minitest testing framework works in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I just started to learn testing with `minitest` but it sounds very confusing to me. What does this statement means?

```
test 'should not save simulations without name' do
 post = Post.new
 assert !post.save, 'Saved the simulations without a name'
end
```

## Post Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name , :type
  belongs_to :user
  before_create :check_validation
  validates :type,  :inclusion => { :in => 1..10, :message => 'The row must be between 1 and 10' }

 private
 def check_validation(data, type)
  ....
 end
```

What would be the `minitest` method for following conditions:

- check if `name`, `type` parameter exist when creating a new object of `Post` class. How can I do it `post_test` class?
- Is this `test` method are checking the presence of `name` in `post`?
- How can I test `check_Validation` through `PostTest` class?
- How to check throw error if `posts` is not belong to users?

I have already created `post.yml` file and `user.yml` file. How to proceed again. I tried to read `ruby` official documentation but it is not very helpful.

Thanks in adnvance

## Edit 1

my yml file

```
one:
  name: 'test'
  type: 3
  user_id: 1
```

I tried :

```
test 'Post must have all parameters' do
assert assigns(:one).valid?
```

end

Comment: I would highly recommend "The Minitest Cookbook" by Chris Kottom.

Comment: Look into the shoulda gem.  All that statement is doing is making a new post instance, not setting any attributes and trying to save it.  Then it assert's it didn't save, displaying the message "Saved the simulations without a name" if it did save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check if name, type parameter exist when creating a new object of Post
>   class. How can I do it post_test class?
>
> Is this test method are checking the presence of name in post?

Sort of.  The assertion checks that saving the new Post instance fails, but there are several reasons for that result - e.g. missing `:name` and `:type` attributes, the `before_create` filter that could hijack the save operation.

If you want to test each of these validations individually, you'll want to start with a known valid Post record and manipulate it to trigger each validation to fail.  Usually, I'll have at least one minimally valid record set up in my fixture file - in this case, I'll call it `:mvp`.  Ex:

```
test 'MVP is valid' do
  assert posts(:mvp).valid?, 'Minimum valid Post is invalid'
end

test 'should not save simulations without name' do
  post = posts(:mvp)
  post.name = nil
  assert post.invalid?, 'Post is valid without a name'
end

...
```

For the most part, I find that testing simple validations (presence, simple numericality, etc.) clutters my tests and smells a little like testing the framework instead of my own application code, so I'll often skip them.

> How can I test check_Validation through PostTest class?

`check_validation` is marked as a private method, and in general, you don't want to directly test private methods.  You can, however, verify that the conditions you set on newly created models match your expectations:

```
test 'newly created Post has settings XYZ' do
  post = Post.new(...)
  assert post.save, 'Post could not be saved'
  # assertions to test #check_validations side effects here...
end
```

You don't include the body of your `check_validation` method, so I don't know what you've got in mind here.  With a name like that though, I'm inclined to believe you're trying to do some kind of validation that would be better left to a custom validation method defined using the `validate` method.  See the docs to see whether it applies in your case.

> How to check throw error if posts is not belong to users?

I'd make this a validated condition on your Post class as:

```
class Post
  belongs_to :user
  validates  :user, presence: true
end
```

Hope that helps somewhat. I've tried to answer your questions in a way that will let you get on with your work, but if you're interested in learning to be productive with Rails and Minitest, you're going to want to  do a deeper study of the framework and how it's used with Rails.

Comment: Chris Thanks for this explanation but when I am applying `assigns ` it says no method undefined method assigns

Check the `Edit-1` section

Comment: I am an idiot.  You should use `posts(:one)`, not `assigns(:one)`.  My mistake, and sorry to have misled you.  Not enough coffee yet this morning.

Comment: Incidentally, Rails 5 will be implementing a different take on instance variables and deprecating the `assigns` method when it's released, so if you're already on edge Rails, this won't be available to you - even in controller tests where it would be appropriately used in current Rails releases.

Answer (score 3):

This is a poorly written test, so I can see why you are confused. I assume that there is a companion test that attempts to show that the `Post` can be saved when it has a name.

```
test 'should save simulations with name' do
  post = Post.new name: 'simulator McSimulation'
  assert post.save, 'Must save the simulations with a name'
end

test 'should not save simulations without name' do
  post = Post.new
  assert !post.save, 'Saved the simulations without a name'
end
```

> What does this statement means?

That is a test method. In Minitest there are three main concepts: test class, test method, and assertion method.

### Test Class

A test class is a class that inherits from `Minitest::Test`. It can inherit from it directly:

```
class PostTest < Minitest::Test
end
```

Or it can inherit from it indirectly

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase < Minitest::Test
end

class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
end
```

All the testing behavior we use is available because we are creating test classes.

### Test Method

A test method is a method that begins with `test_`, like this:

```
class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_valid
    # do the testing here
  end
end
```

Rails adds some syntax sugar so that test methods can be created by passing a string and block to the `test` method instead:

```
class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "is valid" do
    # do the testing here
  end
end
```

Your statement is using the rails-specific syntax. All test methods in a test class are run by Minitest.

### Assertion method

The test class and test methods are how you structure the test, the assertion method is how you actually do the testing. The most basic way to indicate the code behaves as expected is to pass a truthy value to `assert`, and an optional description to give guidance if the value is ever falsey. This is what your statement is doing. `Post#save` returns a value, which you are negating, and then passing to `assert`.

Minitest defines [many more assertion methods](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html).

### Improving the test

I said this was a poorly written test. What do I mean by that? Well, first off, the assertion could fail for any number of reasons, so this test isn't as specific as it needs to be. Here are some changes I would make:

1) The `refute` method is the invert of `assert`, so I would use `refute value` instead of `assert !value`.

```
test 'should not save simulations without name' do
  post = Post.new
  refute post.save, 'Saved the simulations without a name'
end
```

2) Calling `save` actually sends the data to the database, which is slow and should be avoided when possible. Use `valid?` instead of `save`.

```
test 'must not be valid without name' do
  post = Post.new
  refute post.valid?, 'Must be invalid without a name'
end
```

3) Make sure the reason the model isn't valid is because of the reason for the test, specifically that it needs a name. There are several reasons this model is invalid, and would not be saved. We need to be more specific here. The best way to specify this IMO is to check that the model's `errors` object includes a reason for the missing name.

```
test 'must not be valid without name' do
  post = Post.new
  refute post.valid?, 'Must be invalid without a name'
  assert post.errors[:name].any?, 'Must be invalid for missing name'
end
```

Of course we can make that even more specific by specifying a value returned by `post.errors[:name]`. Let's use the `assert_includes` assertion method that asserts that the collection contains a specific value:

```
test 'must not be valid without name' do
  post = Post.new
  refute post.valid?, 'Must be invalid without a name'
  assert_includes post.errors[:name], "can't be blank",
                  'Must be invalid for missing name'
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's really helpful :)
One question: 

Your very first case are failing while the second one are passing. Both are suggesting the same way i.e. we can save the post while do we have name

is `Post.save`  also depends on other `presence` parameters? Is that why it's failing ?

Comment: You want to know that the model can be saved, as well as it cannot be saved. Or can be valid, as well as it can be invalid. The criteria for saving/being valid is up to the object in question. But you should have a test that says with enough correct criteria the model is valid. And then a bunch more tests for each of the ways it can be invalid. That way if something ever changes you have good test coverage to inform you what expectations are not being met.

Comment: ＠blowmage Hi. I just started learning minitest. What if we refactor your last test to look like this?


   `test "must not be valid without name" do`
       `post = Post.new`
       `assert post.invalid?`
       `assert post.errors[:name].any?, 'Post invalid without name'`
     `end`